# How to remove tripmode's kernel module?

Tags: kernel-extensions

A while back I checked out the application Tripmode when I was using a free trial of Setapp (its like Netflix but for Mac Apps), I removed Tripmode however I've noticed the kernel module persists and would like to remove it.

The `kextstat` utility reveals the following:

```
   168    0 0xffffff7f85da8000 0x7000     0x7000    
 ch.tripmode.TripModeNKE (2.0.0) D637B8E3-E64B-3C60-9D43-87F8583B05AC
 <5 4 1>
```

A list of the kernel module system directory shows the following.

```
Nathaniels-MacBook-Pro% pwd
/System/Library/Extensions

Nathaniels-MacBook-Pro% ls -a
.
..
ALF.kext
AMD10000Controller.kext
AMD2400Controller.kext
AMD2600Controller.kext
AMD3800Controller.kext
AMD4600Controller.kext
AMD4800Controller.kext
AMD5000Controller.kext
AMD6000Controller.kext
AMD7000Controller.kext
AMD8000Controller.kext
AMD9000Controller.kext
AMD9300Controller.kext
AMD9500Controller.kext
AMD9510Controller.kext
AMD9515Controller.kext
AMD9520Controller.kext
AMDFramebuffer.kext
AMDLegacyFramebuffer.kext
AMDLegacySupport.kext
AMDMTLBronzeDriver.bundle
AMDRadeonVADriver.bundle
AMDRadeonVADriver2.bundle
AMDRadeonX3000.kext
AMDRadeonX3000GLDriver.bundle
AMDRadeonX4000.kext
AMDRadeonX4000GLDriver.bundle
AMDRadeonX4000HWServices.kext
AMDRadeonX4100.kext
AMDRadeonX4150.kext
AMDRadeonX4200.kext
AMDRadeonX4250.kext
AMDRadeonX5000.kext
AMDRadeonX5000GLDriver.bundle
AMDRadeonX5000HWServices.kext
AMDRadeonX5000MTLDriver.bundle
AMDRadeonX5000Shared.bundle
AMDShared.bundle
AMDSupport.kext
ATIRadeonX2000.kext
ATIRadeonX2000GA.plugin
ATIRadeonX2000GLDriver.bundle
ATIRadeonX2000VADriver.bundle
AirPortBrcmNIC-MFG.kext
Apple16X50Serial.kext
AppleACPIPlatform.kext
AppleAHCIPort.kext
AppleAPIC.kext
AppleActuatorDriver.kext
AppleBacklight.kext
AppleBacklightExpert.kext
AppleBluetoothMultitouch.kext
AppleBluetoothRemote.kext
AppleBusPowerController.kext
AppleCameraInterface.kext
AppleCredentialManager.kext
AppleEFIRuntime.kext
AppleEffaceableNOR.kext
AppleEffaceableStorage.kext
AppleEmbeddedOSSupportHost.kext
AppleFDEKeyStore.kext
AppleFIVRDriver.kext
AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless.kext
AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib.kext
AppleFWAudio.kext
AppleFileSystemDriver.kext
AppleGFXHDA.kext
AppleGraphicsControl.kext
AppleGraphicsPowerManagement.kext
AppleHDA.kext
AppleHIDALSService.kext
AppleHIDKeyboard.kext
AppleHIDMouse.kext
AppleHPET.kext
AppleHPM.kext
AppleHSSPIHIDDriver.kext
AppleHSSPISupport.kext
AppleHV.kext
AppleHWSensor.kext
AppleIRController.kext
AppleInputDeviceSupport.kext
AppleIntelBDWGraphics.kext
AppleIntelBDWGraphicsFramebuffer.kext
AppleIntelBDWGraphicsGLDriver.bundle
AppleIntelBDWGraphicsMTLDriver.bundle
AppleIntelBDWGraphicsVADriver.bundle
AppleIntelBDWGraphicsVAME.bundle
AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement.kext
AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient.kext
AppleIntelFramebufferAzul.kext
AppleIntelFramebufferCapri.kext
AppleIntelGraphicsShared.bundle
AppleIntelHD3000Graphics.kext
AppleIntelHD3000GraphicsGA.plugin
AppleIntelHD3000GraphicsGLDriver.bundle
AppleIntelHD3000GraphicsVADriver.bundle
AppleIntelHD4000Graphics.kext
AppleIntelHD4000GraphicsGLDriver.bundle
AppleIntelHD4000GraphicsMTLDriver.bundle
AppleIntelHD4000GraphicsVADriver.bundle
AppleIntelHD5000Graphics.kext
AppleIntelHD5000GraphicsGLDriver.bundle
AppleIntelHD5000GraphicsMTLDriver.bundle
AppleIntelHD5000GraphicsVADriver.bundle
AppleIntelHDGraphics.kext
AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB.kext
AppleIntelHDGraphicsGA.plugin
AppleIntelHDGraphicsGLDriver.bundle
AppleIntelHDGraphicsVADriver.bundle
AppleIntelHSWVA.bundle
AppleIntelIVBVA.bundle
AppleIntelKBLGraphics.kext
AppleIntelKBLGraphicsFramebuffer.kext
AppleIntelKBLGraphicsGLDriver.bundle
AppleIntelKBLGraphicsMTLDriver.bundle
AppleIntelKBLGraphicsVADriver.bundle
AppleIntelKBLGraphicsVAME.bundle
AppleIntelLpssDmac.kext
AppleIntelLpssGspi.kext
AppleIntelLpssI2C.kext
AppleIntelLpssI2CController.kext
AppleIntelLpssSpiController.kext
AppleIntelLpssUARTCommon.kext
AppleIntelLpssUARTv0.kext
AppleIntelLpssUARTv1.kext
AppleIntelMCEReporter.kext
AppleIntelPCHPMC.kext
AppleIntelSKLGraphics.kext
AppleIntelSKLGraphicsFramebuffer.kext
AppleIntelSKLGraphicsGLDriver.bundle
AppleIntelSKLGraphicsMTLDriver.bundle
AppleIntelSKLGraphicsVADriver.bundle
AppleIntelSKLGraphicsVAME.bundle
AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB.kext
AppleIntelSNBVA.bundle
AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking.kext
AppleKextExcludeList.kext
AppleKeyStore.kext
AppleLPC.kext
AppleLSIFusionMPT.kext
AppleMCCSControl.kext
AppleMCP89RootPortPM.kext
AppleMIDIBluetoothDriver.plugin
AppleMIDIFWDriver.plugin
AppleMIDIIACDriver.plugin
AppleMIDIRTPDriver.plugin
AppleMIDIUSBDriver.plugin
AppleMatch.kext
AppleMikeyHIDDriver.kext
AppleMobileDevice.kext
AppleMobileFileIntegrity.kext
AppleMultitouchDriver.kext
AppleOSXUSBNCM.kext
AppleOSXWatchdog.kext
AppleOnboardSerial.kext
ApplePlatformEnabler.kext
AppleRAID.kext
AppleRAIDCard.kext
AppleRTC.kext
AppleSDXC.kext
AppleSEPManager.kext
AppleSMBIOS.kext
AppleSMBusController.kext
AppleSMBusPCI.kext
AppleSMC.kext
AppleSMCLMU.kext
AppleSMCRTC.kext
AppleSRP.kext
AppleSSE.kext
AppleSmartBatteryManager.kext
AppleStorageDrivers.kext
AppleThunderboltDPAdapters.kext
AppleThunderboltEDMService.kext
AppleThunderboltIP.kext
AppleThunderboltNHI.kext
AppleThunderboltPCIAdapters.kext
AppleThunderboltUTDM.kext
AppleTopCase.kext
AppleTyMCEDriver.kext
AppleUSBACM.kext
AppleUSBAudio.kext
AppleUSBCDC.kext
AppleUSBCommon.kext
AppleUSBDMM.kext
AppleUSBDisplays.kext
AppleUSBECM.kext
AppleUSBEEM.kext
AppleUSBEthernet.kext
AppleUSBEthernetHost.kext
AppleUSBFTDI.kext
AppleUSBMultitouch.kext
AppleUSBNCM.kext
AppleUSBNetworking.kext
AppleUSBSerial.kext
AppleUSBTopCase.kext
AppleUSBWCM.kext
AppleUSBiBridge.kext
AppleUpstreamUserClient.kext
AppleVADriver.bundle
AppleWWANAutoEject.kext
AppleXsanScheme.kext
Apple_iSight.kext
AudioAUUC.kext
BootCache.kext
BridgeAudioCommunication.kext
BridgeAudioController.kext
CellPhoneHelper.kext
CoreStorage.kext
CyProtectDrvOSX.kext
DSACL.ppp
DSAuth.ppp
DVFamily.bundle
Dont Steal Mac OS X.kext
EAP-KRB.ppp
EAP-RSA.ppp
EAP-TLS.ppp
GeForce.kext
GeForceAIRPlugin.bundle
GeForceGA.bundle
GeForceGLDriver.bundle
GeForceMTLDriver.bundle
GeForceTesla.kext
GeForceTeslaGLDriver.bundle
GeForceTeslaVADriver.bundle
GeForceVADriver.bundle
HFS.kext
HFSEncodings.kext
IO80211Family.kext
IO80211FamilyV2.kext
IOACPIFamily.kext
IOAHCIFamily.kext
IOATAFamily.kext
IOAVBFamily.kext
IOAccelerator2D.plugin
IOAcceleratorFamily2.kext
IOAudioFamily.kext
IOBDStorageFamily.kext
IOBluetoothFamily.kext
IOBluetoothHIDDriver.kext
IOBufferCopyController.kext
IOBufferCopyEngineFamily.kext
IOBufferCopyEngineTest.kext
IOCDStorageFamily.kext
IODVDStorageFamily.kext
IOFireWireAVC.kext
IOFireWireFamily.kext
IOFireWireIP.kext
IOFireWireSBP2.kext
IOFireWireSerialBusProtocolTransport.kext
IOGraphicsFamily.kext
IOHDIXController.kext
IOHIDFamily.kext
IOImageLoader.kext
IONDRVSupport.kext
IONVMeFamily.kext
IONetworkingFamily.kext
IOPCIFamily.kext
IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext
IOReportFamily.kext
IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily.kext
IOSCSIParallelFamily.kext
IOSMBusFamily.kext
IOSerialFamily.kext
IOSkywalkFamily.kext
IOSlaveProcessor.kext
IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily.kext
IOStorageFamily.kext
IOStreamFamily.kext
IOSurface.kext
IOThunderboltFamily.kext
IOTimeSyncFamily.kext
IOUSBAttachedSCSI.kext
IOUSBFamily.kext
IOUSBHostFamily.kext
IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext
IOUSBMassStorageDriver.kext
IOUserEthernet.kext
IOVideoFamily.kext
KXLog.kext
KernelRelayHost.kext
L2TP.ppp
Libm.kext
NVDAGF100Hal.kext
NVDAGK100Hal.kext
NVDANV50HalTesla.kext
NVDAResman.kext
NVDAResmanTesla.kext
NVDAStartup.kext
NVMeSMARTLib.plugin
NVSMU.kext
OSvKernDSPLib.kext
PPP.kext
PPPSerial.ppp
PPPoE.ppp
PPTP.ppp
Quarantine.kext
Radius.ppp
RemoteVirtualInterface.kext
SMARTLib.plugin
SMCMotionSensor.kext
Sandbox.kext
System.kext
TMSafetyNet.kext
acfs.kext
acfsctl.kext
apfs.kext
autofs.kext
cd9660.kext
cddafs.kext
corecapture.kext
corecrypto.kext
eficheck.kext
exfat.kext
iPodDriver.kext
mcxalr.kext
msdosfs.kext
ntfs.kext
pmtelemetry.kext
pthread.kext
smbfs.kext
triggers.kext
udf.kext
vecLib.kext
webcontentfilter.kext
webdav_fs.kext
Nathaniels-MacBook-Pro%
```

I cannot find the kext file for tripmode's extension to delete it. Since I am not using tripmode I do not want to leave a potentially outdated kernel module running.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kernel modules don't necessarily have to reside /System/Library/Extensions. Another common kext folder is /Library/Extensions.

The TripMode kext resides in /Library/Application Support/TripMode/ though.

You can remove the folder manually. The app also contains an uninstall script:

```
TripMode.app/Contents/Resources/Uninstall.command
```

I will list other files and folders mentioned in the script to look at and remove eventually:

```
...
sudo rm -Rf "/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/TripMode"
sudo rm -Rf "/Library/Application Support/TripMode"
defaults delete ch.tripmode.TripMode
sudo rm -Rf "/Users/$USER/Library/Preferences/ch.tripmode.TripMode.plist"
sudo launchctl remove ch.tripmode.TripMode.HelperTool
sudo launchctl remove ch.tripmode.nke.TripMode
sudo rm -Rf "/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/ch.tripmode.TripMode.HelperTool"
sudo rm -Rf "/Library/LaunchDaemons/ch.tripmode.nke.TripMode.plist"
sudo rm -Rf "/Library/LaunchDaemons/ch.tripmode.TripMode.HelperTool.plist"
sudo osascript -e 'tell Application "System Events" to delete every login item whose name contains "TripMode"'
...
```

Comment: Thanks for this, very helpful. Just wanted to comment for future readers that you can run the `Uninstall.command` script from the terminal and that it does remove the kext.